# Winforms database connection in form_load

Tags: database, winforms

I'm not posting any code here, because the question is more general.  So I need to populate datagrid with values by calling table adapter's methods (2 tier app).  Usually I do that in form load event.  Since recently though, database server becomes unavailable which results in a hanging form.  That's nasty.
Could you share some common scenarios you use to avoid that?
May be I should rather do that in Shown event?  And yet better do it asynchronously, say with a backgroundworker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do in this way:
 - I disable datagrids and show some message in a `StatusBar`
 - In `Shown` event I start a `BackgroundWorker` that loads from db and fills datasets
 - When worker completes its job I enable datagrids...

In this way your form can handle user inputs without hanging or having refresh problems...